# Ubuntu 14.04.1 howto set a short non complex password for very kiddies?

Tags: password

I tried different things: edit /etc/pam.d/common-password and /usr/share/pam-configs/unix, none worked, account remains disabled, I can't set the password, the "Change" button remains grayed :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just open terminal

Type

```
sudo passwd username
```

Then type your old password then new password.

Retry

And done

Comment: Thank you man: this simply .... worked :)  why do I forget basics? Surely because I just don't know them at all. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad, I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You may have simply not unlocked the user accounts menu.

On the top right of the user accounts menu is an **Unlock** button.

Click it and enter your password when asked (or the admin password if it is different).

You will then be able to change the password, create accounts or set auto login.

[image]

Comment: The change button would not even show when users management is locked.